# To specify font size in pixels (px) using the Quill library in a Vue 3 environment, for example, (2px, 4px, 8px)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quill

I'm having difficulty customizing the font size in pixels (px) using the Quill library. Below is the HTML and JavaScript code

```
    <template>
    <QuillEditor
    ref="myQuillEditor"
    @blur="onEditorBlur"
    @focus="onEditorFocus"
    @ready="onEditorReady"
    @text-change="onEditorChange"
    class="form-control"
    style="height: 800px;"
    :toolbar="toolbar"
    required
    /></template>


    import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
    import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
    import Quill from 'quill';
    let SizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
    SizeStyle.whitelist = ['10px', '12px', '14px', '16px', '18px', '20px', '24px', '30px',   '32px','36px','48px','60px','72px','96px'];
    Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);
    export default {
    components: {
    QuillEditor
    },
    data() {
    return {toolbar: [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
        [{ 'background': [] }, { 'color': [] }],
        [{ 'font': [] }],
        [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
        [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
        [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],
        [{ 'size': [false, '10px', '12px', '14px', '16px', '18px', '20px', '24px',       '30px','32px','36px','48px','60px','72px','96px'] }],
        [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
        [{ 'align': [] }],
        ['clean'],
        ['link', 'image', 'video']    
    ]
    }
    },
    mounted() {
    this.$refs.myQuillEditor.quill.on('text-change', () => {
      let range = this.$refs.myQuillEditor.quill.getSelection();
      if (range) {
        let format = this.$refs.myQuillEditor.quill.getFormat(range);
        let sizeDropdown = document.querySelector('.ql-size .ql-picker-label');
        if (sizeDropdown) {
          sizeDropdown.textContent = format.size || 'Normal';
        }
      }
    });
    },
    };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Z4g.png)
I made an attempt, and the result is as follows. However, when selecting the font size, the text only appears as 'Normal.